# Getting "An expression is too long or complex to compile" when using c# target

Tags: c#, antlr4

I've finally got my full grammar up earlier today and ran into the "String is too long" Java issue.

I understand that this problem has been resolved but I was afraid of running into other limitations so I decided to switch to using the C# target.  I'm an experienced C++ programmer and learned Java to be able to use Antlr4, switching to C# is no big deal, just a new syntax to learn.

I am now getting the message:
1>CSC : fatal error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

There's no other information provided.
Has anyone seen this one before with code generated by Antlr4?
I searched the web for the message but found nothing that could help (many references to older bugs that are supposed to be fixed).

My project is currently composed of a single .cs file along with 2 .g4 file (lexer and parser grammars).

The grammar is pretty complex (implement a language define in an IEEE standard).

I originally implemented a subset of the grammar using the Java target without any issues.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Here's some additional information.  I am using Visual Studio 2012.
It seems to be the same a different version of the Java issue I originally saw.

I was able to create a sample C# file containing just the line :

```
public static readonly string _serializedATN =
    "\x5\x3\x176\x234A\x4\x2\t\x2\x4\x3\t\x3\x4\x4\t\x4\x4\x5\t\x5\x4\x6\t"+
    "\x6\x4\a\t\a\x4\b\t\b\x4\t\t\t\x4\n\t\n\x4\v\t\v\x4\f\t\f\x4\r\t\r\x4"+
    "\xE\t\xE\x4\xF\t\xF\x4\x10\t\x10\x4\x11\t\x11\x4\x12\t\x12\x4\x13\t\x13"+
    "\x4\x14\t\x14\x4\x15\t\x15\x4\x16\t\x16\x4\x17\t\x17\x4\x18\t\x18\x4\x19"+
    "\t\x19\x4\x1A\t\x1A\x4\x1B\t\x1B\x4\x1C\t\x1C\x4\x1D\t\x1D\x4\x1E\t\x1E"+
    "\x4\x1F\t\x1F\x4 \t \x4!\t!\x4\"\t\"\x4#\t#\x4$\t$\x4%\t%\x4&\t&\x4\'"+
    "\t\'\x4(\t(\x4)\t)\x4*\t*\x4+\t+\x4,\t,\x4-\t-\x4.\t.\x4/\t/\x4\x30\t"+
    "\x30\x4\x31\t\x31\x4\x32\t\x32\x4\x33\t\x33\x4\x34\t\x34\x4\x35\t\x35"+
                 ...
                 ...
                 "\x2316\x231E\x2324\x2328\x232D";
```

and the issue was reproducible.  The line is over 4400 lines long.  The C# compiler doesn't seem to be able to handle this many concat.  I was trying to avoid removing the keyword from my language and creating a hash table with them.  This might be my only solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around a found that this could be due to a "deep recursion problem" thrown at the compiler. What this means is that the compiler has problems parsing an expression due to it being too complex. For more information, see [Build error: "An expression is too long or complex to compile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157908/build-error-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile#answer-8160109) and http://ayende.com/blog/3528/setting-out-to-break-the-compiler.