# SvcUtil fails generating XmlSerializer classes

Tags: wcf, xmlserializer, svcutil.exe

I've generated WCF Proxy classes using `svcutil`. And now I am trying to generate `XmlSerializer` classes. `svcUtil` throws this error:

```
Generating XML serializers...
Error: An error occurred in the tool.

Error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile
```

Can anyone advise? Is there any option to see this error details?

Using `.Net fw 4.0`.

Comment: thanks for formatting it for me, @shivam. But an answer to the question would be more appreciated:)

Comment: For a general description of this error and what causes it, see here: [Build error: “An expression is too long or complex to compile”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157908/build-error-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile) and here: [Compiler Error CS1647](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json+c%23).  For us to give any more help, we would need to see the inputs to `svcUtil`.

Comment: @dbc, unfortunately I don't know exactly, which one of the services causes this error, but due to the nature of the project I am not in the position to give you the dlls, etc... thanks for the comment anyway