# .Net Framework 4 site compilation error due to loading too many assembly (dll) files. "CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, assemblies

Working on a massive CRM web app which uses a webforms site as the main site to host other modules using iframes. When the site is accessed, it loads all the assemblies, and currently facing a bottleneck with the number of dlls that can be loaded. There's around 1850 dlls, and if I add a new dll I get the following compilation error:

> `Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
> compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
> review the following specific error details and modify your source
> code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1647: An expression is too long or complex
> to compile
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:    Line: 0 Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> ________________________________________ Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
> Version:4.7.3062.0`

The detailed compiler output just shows the paths to all the assemblies. So current situation, if I want to add new assemblies I need to delete something else, or else I get this error.

I'm pretty sure the following line of code is responsible, but I could be wrong:

```
`var ourAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList().FindAll(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME"));`
```

My guess was that the number of dlls is causing the variable holding the list of assemblies to overflow after a certain point. So I tried using two different variables to handle the assemblies instead of one.

```
`var allAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList(); var first1500Assemblies = allAssemblies.Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME")).Take(1500).ToList(); var restOfAssemblies = allAssemblies.Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME")).Skip(1500).ToList(); `
```

No success.

Also tried fiddling around with IIS file size limits.
Adding dlls which don't contain "SITE_NAME" doesn't trigger the error.

Context: This is part of a giant codebase, so I'm looking for solutions that don't require big changes.
I think some kind of dynamic loading strategy instead of loading all the assemblies at once at startup would be a better approach, so I'm currently looking into ways of implementing that but couldn't find a fix yet.

The full method that holds the above code:

```
        public static SystemVersionInfo GetSystemVersionInfo(out MessageSet msg)
    {
        msg = null;
        SystemVersionInfo toReturn = new SystemVersionInfo();
        try
        {
            var ourAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList().FindAll(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME"));

            List<LibInfo> SITEAssembliesInfo = new List<LibInfo>();
            ourAssemblies.ForEach(a =>
            {
                SITEAssembliesInfo.Add(new LibInfo() { name = a.GetName().Name, version = a.GetName().Version.ToString(), BuildDate = a.GetLinkerTime() });

            });
            toReturn.SITELibs = SITEAssembliesInfo.OrderBy(l => l.name).ToList();

            List<LibInfo> otherAssembliesInfo = new List<LibInfo>();
            var otherAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList().FindAll(a => !a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME"));
            otherAssemblies.ForEach(a =>
            {
                otherAssembliesInfo.Add(new LibInfo() { name = a.GetName().Name, version = a.GetName().Version.ToString() });

            });
            toReturn.ThirdPartyLibs = otherAssembliesInfo.OrderBy(l => l.name).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = MessageCreate.CreateErrorMessage(0, ex, "GetSystemVersionInfo", "SITE_NAME.THIS_APP.WEB.dll");
        }

        return toReturn;

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would be related to your issue but I'd replace `GetAssemblies().ToList().FindAll(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME"))` with `GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME")).ToList()`. You could even drop the `ToList` and then use a regular `foreach` loop for the `IEnumerable<T>` you would get from `Where`. Don't realise an `IEnumerable<T>` as a `List<T>` or `T[]` if you don't have to.

Comment: I also notice that you are calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` twice. Don't do that. It returns an array so don't just throw that away and then get the same data again moments later. Call that once and assign the result to a variable, then use that variable as the root for whatever filtering you need to do later on. That filtering won;t affect the original array so you can use it as many times as you like.

Comment: Also, instead of looping over the list of `Assemblies` and adding each one to an existing `List<T>`, you can chain a `Select` after the `Where` to generate the `LibInfo` objects and call `ToList` on the result. First, `var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();`, then `var siteLibInfos = assemblies.Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("SITE_NAME")).Select(a => new LibInfo {...}).ToList();`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1647 "There was a stack overflow in the compiler...". This isn't a problem with executing your code.

Comment: I also notice that you create a `List<T>` and populate it, then you call `OrderBy` and `ToList`, so that's wasteful again. If you're going to create and populate the `List` that way, call `Sort` on it to order it in place, so you don't have to create yet another `List`. If you do it the way I suggested then you can just add the `OrderBy` call into the chain, between `Select` and `ToList`. Whoever wrote this code really needs to put more thought into where new objects are being created and which of those is actually required.

Comment: @jmcilhinney will check out your suggestions, thanks. And yes, whoever who wrote this has done it in a very thoughtless manner. This is just one issue, there are hundreds of other potential issues waiting to happen because of improperly planned coding by ppl who wrote this,

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I love how the doc goes, "There was a stack overflow in the compiler ... If your code is valid, get help at StackOverflow".  @MuhammadNazeer, stop looking at the code. As Jeremy said, the compiler doesn't run your code. Running [`msbuild` on the command line against your solution/project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) and specifying `-verbosity:diag` may give you a better picture on what's happening with the compiler.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157908/build-error-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile, specially the answer from Eric Lippert that explains why the error you get is extremely unhelpful and why the culprit will be hard to diagnose. The # of dlls is a theme in the answers there as well by the way.